# Dropped image from FloatingScreenshot preview has no NSItemProvider type in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to drag and drop a screenshot from the FloatingPreview into my SwiftUI macOS application.

```
.onDrop(of: ["public.url","public.file-url"], isTargeted: nil) { (items) -> Bool in
            if let item = items.first {
                print(item)
                if let identifier = item.registeredTypeIdentifiers.first {
                  print(identifier)
                }
            }
        }
```

result:

```
<NSItemProvider: 0x600001759500> {types = (
)}
```

As the NSItemProvider has no type I also do not know how to load the data. I am happy for any input!

Thanks,
Jakob

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "public.image" to your code

```
.onDrop(of: ["public.url","public.file-url","public.image"], isTargeted.....
```